# Get All events Performed Before One specific event?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several events and their timestamps in the dataset in BigQuery.

[image]

For my example, I'm using One event: Event 'A'.

I need to figure out **what events** and **with what frequency** are performed by each user **before* doing Event 'A' and not **after**

This is the query I'm using:

```
select distinct_id,Lead(event,1) over (Partition by distinct_id order by ConvertedEventDate ) 
as nextEvent,ConvertedEventDate from Table 
order by 1
```

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Hello there, Can you please provide an example of your data and a full SQL you used so far with what is the expected result

Comment: Hello Tamir, Firstly Here is an example of data http://take.ms/CX2Ex. You can see the events coming after the particular event I am interested in. I only need rows before this event.   Secondly, here is the query                                                  
(select  distinct_id,Lead(event,1) over (Partition by distinct_id order by ConvertedEventDate ) as nextEvent,ConvertedEventDate 
from `Table` order by 1 )